Omit roles creation from pg_dumpall
How can I omit in output from pg_dumpall this roles creation part:

--
-- Roles
--

CREATE ROLE admin;
ALTER ROLE admin WITH NOSUPERUSER INHERIT NOCREATEROLE CREATEDB LOGIN NOREPLICATION NOBYPASSRLS PASSWORD 'SCRAM-SHA-';
CREATE ROLE user;
ALTER ROLE user WITH NOSUPERUSER INHERIT NOCREATEROLE NOCREATEDB LOGIN NOREPLICATION NOBYPASSRLS PASSWORD 'SCRAM-SHA-';
CREATE ROLE postgres;
ALTER ROLE postgres WITH SUPERUSER INHERIT CREATEROLE CREATEDB LOGIN REPLICATION BYPASSRLS PASSWORD 'SCRAM-SHA-';
CREATE ROLE zabbix;
ALTER ROLE zabbix WITH NOSUPERUSER INHERIT NOCREATEROLE NOCREATEDB LOGIN NOREPLICATION NOBYPASSRLS PASSWORD 'SCRAM-SHA-';


Thank you for any hint.

I did it, in the end, by deleting lines with CREATE ROLE and ALTER ROLE from final output file.


You can't. 2) What problem are you trying to solve?


@AdrianKlaver Restore db from one stage to another. But users on target stage are already created and have different passwords.

From here pg_dumpall --no-role-passwords. Though if the if the roles are already there the restore will just do something like psql:16_main.sql:14: ERROR:  role "adrian" already exists and continue on leaving the existing roles and their passwords alone anyway.

Also  Restore db from one stage to another. implies you are only interested in a single database in the cluster. If that is the case you should be using pg_dump, that will not include the roles as they are global to a cluster.

@AdrianKlaver I am sorry, my fault, it was typo. I wrote db but meant dbs.
